# Windows 8.1 Modern titles has a little down arrow in right bottom corner

Tags: modern-ui, windows-8.1

I have installed a **fresh copy of Windows 8.1** (not upgrade from Win 8, fresh install) and after I **logged in my Microsoft account again** almost **all the titles** on my Start screen **have a little down arrow in the right bottom corner**. My question is: Why? The apps are installed and there isn't any update for them, and I can't click on the arrows (when I do it the application start), so why they are there?

A part of my Startscreen showing the arrows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQiNk.png]

Comment: Have you tried to unnstall them them install them?

Comment: What a simple solution, and I have not think previously to that! Thanks :) After Reinstall the down arrow is not shown anymore.

Comment: @Ramhound: might want to post that as an answer ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I will let somebody else take the credit.

Comment: Also, that looks a lot like the 'updates' symbol - I wonder if updating them from the windows store would have helped.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There was no update in the sore for the apps. But reinstall helped. So problem solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reinstall them. As simple as that. Right-click on the program title, select uninstall from the menu on the bottom of the screen which came up, then go to Windows Store and download them again. Done.